# How to insert csv file contents to postgreSQL table using pySpark?

Tags: postgresql, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to insert data from a csv file to a postgreSQL table. I have written code for fetching data from a csv file like this

```
myData = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").load("D:/sample.csv")
```

I got the file contents in 'myData' variable.I have written database connection like the following.

```
url = 'postgresql://myPath';

properties = {
    "user": "postgres",
    "driver": "org.postgresql.Driver",
    "password":""
};

df = DataFrameReader(sqlContext).jdbc(
    url='jdbc:%s' % url, table='pyspark_user', properties=properties
);
```

When I print df, it showing like this

```
DataFrame[id: int, firstname: string, lastname: string, email: string, password: string]
```

How can I insert the rows of 'myData' to the table 'pyspark_user'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myData.write.format('jdbc').options(
      url='jdbc:%s' % url,
      driver='org.postgresql.Driver',
      dbtable='pyspark_user',
      user='postgres',
      password='').mode('append').save()
```